# How to resolve slideout animation not being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

so I have a simple side bar that I want to slide in and out using css animation, now the slide animation in is working the problem that I am facing is making the animation for the slideout to work.

Can I please get help on that..

**Html(Sidebar)**

```
<div class="SideBarMenu" id="SideBarMenu">
    <div class="sidebar-menu-header">
        <h2 class="nav-bleft-companyname">
            Sofast<span class="nav-bleft-periodmark">Cart.</span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <h4 class="sidebar-menuLink">MenuItem1</h4>
    <h4 class="sidebar-menuLink">MenuItem2</h4>
    <h4 class="sidebar-menuLink">MenuItem3</h4>
    <h4 class="sidebar-menuLink">MenuItem4</h4>
    <h4 class="sidebar-menuLink">MenuItem5</h4>
</div>
```

**JS Function triggered to toggle menu**

```
const OpenMenu = () => {
    const menu = document.getElementById("SideBarMenu");
    if (menu.style.display === "block") {
        menu.classList.add("sidebar-closed");
        menu.style.animation = "slideOut 0.4s backwards";
        menu.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        menu.style.display = "block";
        menu.style.animation = "slideIn 0.4s forwards";
        menu.classList.remove("sidebar-closed");
    }
};
```

**Side Bar css**

```
.SideBarMenu {
  top: 0% !important;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  transform: translateX(-350px);
  padding: 2rem;
}

.sidebar-menuLink {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-350px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css transition to achieve that. I also advise you to put all your styles in css classes, you don't need to apply the styles in javascript.

```js
const animate = () => {
    const elem = document.getElementById("my-elem");
    if (!elem.classList.contains('elem-out')) {
        elem.classList.add("elem-out");
    } else {
        elem.classList.remove("elem-out");
    }
};

const btn = document.getElementById("my-btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", animate)
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.elem:not(.elem-out) {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.elem-out {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(-350px);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-elem" class="elem"></div>
<button id="my-btn">toggle animate</button>
```

Do not change the display property, the transition will brake. There's no transition for propperty like display, if you want a fadeIn / fadeOut effect too, you can put a transition on opacity property